# mongoose.createConnection() - model is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, express, mongoose

I'm trying create multiple connections to my mongodb Cloud.
The old code for single connection with mongoose.connect() is still fine, but when I changed to mongoose.createConnection() for multiple connections, I got this error:

[TypeError: conn1.model is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Z2DA.png)

Edited: I've removed .asPromise() behind mongoose.createConnection(process.env.MONGO_URI) but it is still the same problem

My code:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
require("dotenv").config();

const conn1 = mongoose.createConnection(process.env.MONGO_URI)
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        uniquie: true,
        lowercase: true,
    },
});

module.exports = conn1.model("users", UserSchema);
```

Comment: Directly call the `mongoose.createConnection()` by removing your `.asPromise()` method call.

Comment: already removed `.asPromise()` but still same problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `then()` method in handling successful connections to your MongoDB database. Also use handle errors

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
require("dotenv").config();

const conn1 = mongoose.createConnection(process.env.MONGO_URI);
conn1.then(() => {
    const UserSchema = new Schema({
        username: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
            lowercase: true,
        },
    });

    module.exports = conn1.model("users", UserSchema);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error("Connection error:", error);
});
```

Comment: Still can’t, thank you verymuch. I wil spend more efforts to investigate this case

Answer (score 0):

try remove .asPromise(. I think it is usefull

Comment: Yeah thank you, already removed .asPromise() but still the same problem.

Comment: I follow the same docs and many videos on Utube, but my code does not work